# What is the safest way to leave my MacBook on 24/7 with macOS Mojave?

Tags: macbook-pro, mojave, battery, sleep-wake, hibernate

I used to use `sudo pmset -a hibernatemode 25` to try setting my MacBook to hibernate instead of sleep, so that it pulls power away from the RAM/hard drives, etc. and puts the laptop into a proper sleep. A few major updates ago (maybe El Capitan), `pmset ... 25` no longer worked to set my MacBook into hibernate/safe sleep. I'm using a MacBook 13" from 2017. Is hibernate no longer supported on this model?

After hearing about the defect in the [15-inch MacBooks](https://support.apple.com/15-inch-macbook-pro-battery-recall) from 2017, I have to admit that I'm concerned they'll find an issue with 13-inch MacBooks as well, and I want to be as safe as possible.

I use a lot of applications whose state needs to be maintained across many days for development and testing, so shutting down my computer every day is not efficient nor is it a viable option.

Here is my `pmset -g custom` after running `sudo pmset -a hibernatemode 25` to try enabling hibernate mode again:

`pmset -g custom`

```
Battery Power:
 lidwake              1
 autopoweroff         1
 standbydelayhigh     86400
 autopoweroffdelay    28800
 proximitywake        0
 standby              1
 standbydelaylow      10800
 ttyskeepawake        1
 highstandbythreshold 50
 powernap             0
 gpuswitch            2
 hibernatefile        /var/vm/sleepimage
 hibernatemode        25
 displaysleep         5
 sleep                180
 tcpkeepalive         1
 halfdim              1
 acwake               0
 lessbright           1
 disksleep            10
AC Power:
 lidwake              1
 autopoweroff         1
 standbydelayhigh     86400
 autopoweroffdelay    28800
 proximitywake        1
 standby              1
 standbydelaylow      10800
 ttyskeepawake        1
 hibernatemode        25
 powernap             1
 gpuswitch            2
 hibernatefile        /var/vm/sleepimage
 highstandbythreshold 50
 womp                 1
 displaysleep         10
 networkoversleep     0
 sleep                10
 tcpkeepalive         1
 halfdim              1
 acwake               0
 disksleep            10
```

`pmset -g cap`

```
Capabilities for AC Power:
 displaysleep
 disksleep
 sleep
 womp
 acwake
 lidwake
 halfdim
 gpuswitch
 standby
 standbydelayhigh
 standbydelaylow
 highstandbythreshold
 powernap
 ttyskeepawake
 hibernatemode
 hibernatefile
 autopoweroff
 tcpkeepalive
 autopoweroffdelay
 proximitywake
```

Comment: If your computer 'hibernates', it's not able to communicate with any other device, or it's own hard drive for that matter.
Hibernation puts the state of your system into the RAM's and 'shut's down'. The only thing that' in real need of power at that point are your RAM's! (RAM memory is volatile so it must be constantly powered to prevent data loss). I suggest you to activate 'Power Nap' in your power setings. When Power Nap is activated, the computer goes into 'Sleep' mode, not 'Hibernation'.
Check this info on Apple's website: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204032

Comment: Please edit your OQ to include the output of `pmset -g custom`.

Comment: SInce you don't have a 15-inch MacBook model mid-2015, you are not concerned by the racall program you referenced.

Comment: @DaktaMoriamé Sleep locks the state of the system into the RAM. Hibernate copies the RAM onto the hard drive in `/var/vm/sleepimage` and then powers off the RAM. I'll check out Power Nap.

Comment: @dan Added it! I know that my 13-inch isn't part of the recall program, but the recall program still has me spooked with how I use my MacBook.

Comment: @NobleUplift Damn, I'm so sorry and ashamed! My bad... You are absolutely right, I mixed those 2. But, Power Nap is probably going to be what you are looking for.

Comment: @DaktaMoriamé The file that hibernate saves to is paradoxically called the `sleepimage` file, so don't worry about it! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say "Nothing".  Assuming there is an defective battery, you can't 'manage' its safety with any specific behaviour. It could fail and overheat while in use, or while charging.

The odd recall notwithstanding, Apple has worked very hard at making laptops use minimal power when closed, while also allowing some necessary background tasks; and then letting them spring back to life when you open the lid.

Modern SSDs use a fraction of the power of the old mechanical hard drives that needed to be spun down to save energy.

I rarely turn off my 2014 MacBook Pro, and only reboot it when updating the OS or troubleshooting.

Comment: There's no such thing as 0 risk, you're definitely right. Thanks for putting me more at ease!

Comment: Thank you for giving me your use case and letting me know that I'm not the only one who uses MacBooks like this! I've been running `hibernatemode 25` and it seems to be working just fine. I could always go back to turning off my MacBook on weekends if I'm that concerned again.

Comment: @NobleUplift I'd say most people leave them on all the time. That's how they're designed to be used. I wouldn't use the non-standard hibernatemode. You'll probably see no noticeable saving. The default is 3.

Answer (score 2):

Your setting of hybernate mode is the one to achieve exactly what you described.

But you are correct. I use this setting since many years and through many versions of MacOS (`Yosemite`, `El Capitan`, `Sierra` & `High Sierra`).
From memory I reported many times the same problem to Apple about this mode failing on output of hibernation when the battery was nearly empty.

I guess there is a problem about correctly evaluating the power required to make the `/var/vm/sleepimage` dump of the virtual memory.
Since they never answered me, I guess they never fully understood the problem.

Now I know for sure that the function `lidwake` is failing.

> Is hibernate no longer supported on this model?

No it is still supported.

But since a negative question is leading to confusing answers
here is a clearer one.

The command to check directly the availability of this function is:

```
pmset -g cap
```

and look for the key function: `hybernatemode`

Another way to detect if a Mac is coming from a sleep or an hibernation state is through:

```
nvram 'boot-args=-v'
```

which will turn the boot code in verbose mode.

Comment: I'll try sleeping my computer for more than 5 minutes with no power to see if it comes out of hibernation or sleep mode.

Comment: To shorten your testing cycle I suggest you: `pmset autopoweroffdelay 1`. Don't forget to reset to its default value afterward.

Comment: I believe I had it set to `25` before posting this question, but I've had it set to `25` for two months now, and I think it's hibernating. Thank you for your answer!